# Trying to get property of non-object in codeignitor?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
public function login()
{  
    $this->load->view('user/login');
}

public function enteruser()
{
     $data = array(
        'user_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'user_pasword' => $this->input->post('password')            
    );


    $make_call = $this->callAPI('http://demo.theoneinfotech.com/dating/user/login', json_encode($data));
    //print_r($make_call);exit;

    $response['result'] = json_decode($make_call, true);
    echo $make_call[1]->message; exit;
    //var_dump($result["message"]);exit;

    $this->load->view('user/welcome');
```

When I call the login api then I got this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in codeignitor.

Please tell me how to handle response from `$make_call`.

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($make_call)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you are trying to print the value from $make_call make sure that the endpoint should return some response.
Ex:

```
$make_call = $this->callAPI('http://demo.theoneinfotech.com/dating/user/login', json_encode($data));
//should return some data
```

out a debugger/vardump to see the outcome of **$make_call** 
In your code

```
$response['result'] = json_decode($make_call, true);
 echo $make_call[1]->message;// remove this 
exit;
```

you don't know whether $make_call[1] is an object or not. 
So you can handle something like this

```
if($response['result'] && $response['result']->message){
  //your operation if you get data
}
else{
//your failed operation
}
```

Comment: use isset($response['result']    and  isset($response['result']->message  if possible. so you don't get warning when these keys are missing